# Determining the weather station closest to a object

Tags: r

I am writing a script in r to determine the closest weather station to an object. Except, when running my code it automatically returns the weather station three (indicated by Cam in Table Station) being closest to all objects which is not the case. Any ideas why this is the case? I would also like to get the station name instead of just the index if possible.

Code:

```
 earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
 {
 rad <- pi/180
 a1 <- lat1 * rad
 a2 <- long1 * rad
 b1 <- lat2 * rad
 b2 <- long2 * rad
 dlon <- b2 - a2
 dlat <- b1 - a1
 a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
 c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
 R <- 6378.145
 d <- R * c
 return(d)
 }


 for (i in 1:length(Object$Lat))
 {
     for (j in 1:length(Station$Lat))
     {
         a[j] <- earth.dist(Station$Lon[j], Station$Lat[j], Object$Lon[i], Object$Lat[i])
     }
     index <- which(min(a) %in% a)
     Object$Station[i] = Station$Station[index]
 }
```

Station Table:

```
Station Lat Lon
SF  37.7749 -122.4194
CH  41.8781 -87.6298
Cam 52.2053 -0.1218
```

Object Table:

```
Object  Lat Lon
1   38.983  -123.092
2   36.941  -121.767
3   36.121  -121.084
4   38.415  -121.787
5   36.854  -121.362
6   38.651  -121.218
7   37.314  -120.386
8   36.158  -119.8514
9   38.599  -121.54
10  35.335  -120.734
11  34.841  -120.212
12  38.004  -122.02
13  37.599  -122.052
14  38.0903 -122.5267
15  37.664  -121.885
16  51.50853    -0.076132
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to reinvent the wheel w/r/t earth distance calcs.

Data:

```
read.table(text="Station Lat Lon
SF  37.7749 -122.4194
CH  41.8781 -87.6298
Cam 52.2053 -0.1218", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE) -> stations

read.table(text="Object  Lat Lon
1   38.983  -123.092
2   36.941  -121.767
3   36.121  -121.084
4   38.415  -121.787
5   36.854  -121.362
6   38.651  -121.218
7   37.314  -120.386
8   36.158  -119.8514
9   38.599  -121.54
10  35.335  -120.734
11  34.841  -120.212
12  38.004  -122.02
13  37.599  -122.052
14  38.0903 -122.5267
15  37.664  -121.885
16  51.50853    -0.076132", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE) -> objs
```

Code:

```
library(geosphere)
library(tidyverse)

find_closest_station <- function(lon, lat) {

  mutate(stations, dist=map2_dbl(Lon, Lat, ~distHaversine(c(lon, lat), c(.x, .y)))) %>%
    top_n(-1, wt=dist) %>%
    .$Station

}

mutate(objs, wx_st=map2_chr(Lon, Lat, find_closest_station))
##    Object      Lat         Lon wx_st
## 1       1 38.98300 -123.092000    SF
## 2       2 36.94100 -121.767000    SF
## 3       3 36.12100 -121.084000    SF
## 4       4 38.41500 -121.787000    SF
## 5       5 36.85400 -121.362000    SF
## 6       6 38.65100 -121.218000    SF
## 7       7 37.31400 -120.386000    SF
## 8       8 36.15800 -119.851400    SF
## 9       9 38.59900 -121.540000    SF
## 10     10 35.33500 -120.734000    SF
## 11     11 34.84100 -120.212000    SF
## 12     12 38.00400 -122.020000    SF
## 13     13 37.59900 -122.052000    SF
## 14     14 38.09030 -122.526700    SF
## 15     15 37.66400 -121.885000    SF
## 16     16 51.50853   -0.076132   Cam
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your `which()` logic is off a bit. To illustrate, below always returns `TRUE`, so `which()` returns 1.

```
which("R" %in% LETTERS)
# [1] 1
```

However, below is only `TRUE` at the 18th letter:

```
which(LETTERS == "R")
# [1] 18
```

So simply replace

```
index <- which(min(a) %in% a)
```

With:

```
index <- which(a == min(a))
```

---

Also, consider apply solutions in case you need to stay in base R as you can replace nested `for` with `sapply` (passing in two vectors) and the resulting indexing with `apply`:

```
dist.matrix <- sapply(seq(nrow(Station)), function(x, y) 
                           earth.dist(Station$Lon[x], Station$Lat[x],
                                      Object$Lon[y], Object$Lat[y]), 
                      seq(nrow(Object)))

Object$Station <- apply(dist.matrix, 1, function(i) Station$Station[which(i == min(i))])

Object
#    Object      Lat         Lon       Station
# 1       1 38.98300 -123.092000            SF
# 2       2 36.94100 -121.767000            SF
# 3       3 36.12100 -121.084000            SF
# 4       4 38.41500 -121.787000            SF
# 5       5 36.85400 -121.362000            SF
# 6       6 38.65100 -121.218000            SF
# 7       7 37.31400 -120.386000            SF
# 8       8 36.15800 -119.851400            SF
# 9       9 38.59900 -121.540000            SF
# 10     10 35.33500 -120.734000            SF
# 11     11 34.84100 -120.212000            SF
# 12     12 38.00400 -122.020000            SF
# 13     13 37.59900 -122.052000            SF
# 14     14 38.09030 -122.526700            SF
# 15     15 37.66400 -121.885000            SF
# 16     16 51.50853   -0.076132           Cam
```

---

Even base R's `outer` will work with a transposed *dist.matrix* compared to above `sapply` output so the latter `apply` runs by column margins:

```
dist.mat <- outer(seq(nrow(Station)), seq(nrow(Object)),
                function(x, y) earth.dist(Station$Lon[x], Station$Lat[x],
                                          Object$Lon[y], Object$Lat[y]))

Object$Station <- apply(dist.mat, 2, function(i) Station$Station[which(i == min(i))])
```